# Combining audio sources into one

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.js, node-streams

I am trying to combine all the users voices in a Discord channel into one single mp3 file.[image: codes] As you can see in the image there are different opus streams for each user.

1-) How can I combine that opus streams.
2-) Can I store the buffers in a list then convert it into one opus stream?

Comment: Check out [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg), the [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filter, and the `complexFilter()` function (in fluent-ffmpeg). Hopefully this gets you headed in the right direction.

Comment: I couldn't understand how I can convert these buffers into a audio source by using complexFilter function

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

Here's how I *think* this could be done (I'm not able to test this code at the moment so take it with a grain of salt)

```js
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const fs = require('fs')

ffmpeg()
  // pipe the audio from both streams into ffmpeg
  .input(audioStreamOne)
  .input(audioStreamTwo)
  // use `amix` to combine the streams
  .complexFilter(['amix=inputs=2:duration=longest'])
  // you could either pipe to another stream
  .pipe(audioOutStream)
  // ...or you could save it to a file
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.mp3'))
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert these Buffers into audiostream? Because I'm getting these streams asynchronously and if i combine them directly can lead to issues.

Comment: Also, I am getting this error.
`Error: Only one input stream is supported`

Comment: @AliEren Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to figure out a similar thing.